# Apple App Development over Wireless/Wifi

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, wifi

When developing for Android, I can connect to my Android Phone wirelessly with an app like [Wifi ADB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=en) (or similar).

`adb connect 192.168.1.100` + that (or similar) app = build/push to device/debug with a wireless connection / without the need to physically connect device to computer.

Does that capability exist on the iPhone for developers? If it is available, is it also available for Xamarin Mac Agent while developing from Windows?

Answer (score 2):

yes you just have to configure it in Visual Studio Mac, follow the steps indicated [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debugging_in_xamarin_ios/). But check the following note:

> "Launching of application is still done through the USB cable, so the
>   initial launch will still require you to have the cable plugged. But
>   once started, you can safely unplug and continue your debugging
>   session over WiFi."